# Django allauth doesn't send any email

Tags: django, digital-ocean, django-allauth

I'm using django_allauth for my django project. But no more email is sent (confirmation email, reset password).

It successfully creates a new user, the message that confirms an email has been sent appears and there is also a the redirection to the confirm email page. However I don't receive this email in my inbox and I can't see any error.

Moreover, I use in other app for a contact form the class send_email() and it works.

I've tried to add some print() directly in the code if some variables could be wrong. I've also tried to enable fail_silently

```py
    def send_mail(self, template_prefix, email, context):
        msg = self.render_mail(template_prefix, email, context)
        msg.send(fail_silently=False)
```

My application is hosted on Digital Ocean.
It is running on ubuntu with nginx/gunicorn

I've run the shell in order to try sending some test email and I always received an email with the method send_email() and objects EmailMultiAlternatives.send(), EmailMessage.send().

here is Settings.py

```py
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

# Email identification
EMAIL_HOST = 'myhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myuser'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'myemail@email.com'

# `allauth` config
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username_email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_LIMIT = 5
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS = 1
SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = True
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/' # redirects to homepage.
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to give autorisation in Google seconds verification system to your current app in web development. Go to google second app permissions
Sign in using App Passwords - Google Account Help

Comment: I don't use the smtp of Gmail.

Comment: You need to, otherwise it won't work. Once set the password of particular app, you need to enter that password in that settings.py